# Carbon formatLocalized not working in Blade

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, php-carbon

In a Blade view I have this code

`{{ \Carbon\Carbon::setLocale("es") }}
 {{ $registro->fecha_desde->format("l j F Y") }}<br />
 {{ $registro->fecha_desde->formatLocalized("%A %d %B %Y") }}<br />
 {{ $registro->fecha_desde->diffForHumans() }}`

This does not work, it returns:

```
Friday 30 December 2016
Friday 30 December 2016
dentro de 1 semana
```

So, format() and formatLocalized always returns the date in english format. 
diffForHumans returns the date localized (in spanish in this case).

Am I missing something? cant believe "Carbon's formatLocalized" is not returning localized formated dates....

Comment: Official [Nesbot Carbon docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization).

Answer (score 7):

I found two ways to output dates in other language. add this in the AppServiceProvider

```
    Carbon::setLocale('es');
    setlocale(LC_TIME,'es_ES');

//This output dates in spanish
```

In App.php put 'es' instead 'en'. now you can use FormatLocalized and all Carbon Functions will be in the language that you assign in setLocale.

Note: If you're using Oracle DB add:

```
 setlocale(LC_TIME, config('app.locale'));
```

instead:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME,'es_ES');
```

Answer (score 5):

Found it. 
The problems is \Carbon::setlocale()

This looks ugly but works:

```
{{ setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_MX', 'es', 'ES') }}
{{ $registro->fecha_desde->formatLocalized("%A %d %B %Y") }}
```

Output:

```
es viernes 30 diciembre 2016
```

Comment: so, do you simply removed Carbon::setLocale() from app service provider?

Answer (score 2):

Open `AppServiceProvider.php` 
Call class of carbon `use Carbon\Carbon;`

```
public function boot()
{
  Carbon::setUTF8(true);
  Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
  setlocale(LC_TIME, config('app.locale'));
}
```

in the `config` folder open `app.php`

set `'locale' => 'es',`

on `ubuntu`

```
public function boot()
{
   Carbon::setUTF8(true);
   Carbon::setLocale(config('app.locale'));
   setlocale(LC_TIME,'');
}
```

Comment: Method `setUTF8` is deprecated

Comment: In Laravel 8, you better create a middleware in case you want to use `App::currentLocale()` (which is dynamic) instead of `config('app.locale')` (which is static)

Answer (score 0):

to view formats with additional accents, you have to enable UTF8 encoding, before formatting:

```
\Carbon::setUTF8(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays it's better to use ->isoFormat('dddd DD MMMM YYYY') instead of ->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y') because formatLocalized() is deprecated.

So it can look like this:

```
{{ setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_MX', 'es', 'ES') }}
{{ $registro->fecha_desde->isoFormat('dddd DD MMMM YYYY') }}
```